# FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) and redirect to site not working

Tags: facebook

We are using

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>
```

and for logout:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response)
```

But after clicking on logout button it logs out from facebook, but does not reload the page and `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response)` does not work

Comment: Do you get any error messages or error return values?

Comment: Are you forgetting the second right parenthesis like you do in your title and question? I'm sure you'd get some sort of syntax error but I don't know what language this is since I don't write code that interacts with facebook.

Comment: Hhttp://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/  I don't see what this autologoutlink is.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that you are doing the FB.Event.subscribe inside the window.fbAsyncInit function? For example:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

FB.init({
  ......
)};

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response){
  // User is now logged out
  window.refresh();
)};

};
```

I had a similar problem, and when I had the Event.subscribe outside of the fbAsyncInit it would not fire, but moving it inside fixed the problem. Hopefully this works for you.